# Properties of complex sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, complex-numbers

Let $x_{n}$ be a real sequence and $x_n\rightarrow x(\neq0)$, then we know that for large $n$, $sgn(x_n)=sgn(x)$. But I am looking for a similar result in the case of a complex sequence.
As in case of comples if we use $sgn(z)=z/|z|$ for $z\neq 0$, then if take the sequence $z_n=1+\iota/n$ which is convergent to 1, but $sgn(z_n)\neq 1$ for any $n$.  So, here it does not work like real sequences. Can you please suggest me something that works for complex case too?

Comment: You could look at the sign of the real part or the sign of the imaginary part. But it would be good if you could clarify your motivation.

Comment: For both $X = \mathbb{R}$ and $X = \mathbb{C}$, the function $\operatorname{sgn}(x) = x/|x|$ is continuous away from zero. The difference is that when $X = \mathbb{R}$, the image consists of two values $\pm 1$, while when $X = \mathbb{C}$, the image is the unit circle in the complex plane. What exactly do you want to "work" here?

Answer (score 1):

As @angryavian has commented, you can do this for the real and imaginary parts of a sequence in $\mathbb{C}$. That works because a sequence converges in $\mathbb{C}$ iff its real and imaginary parts converge to the real and imaginary parts of the limit, respectively. It would go something like this:

*Let $z_n=x_n+iy_n$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{C}$, converging to some $x+iy$. If $x\neq 0$, then $\text{sgn}\,x_n=\text{sgn}\,x$ for sufficiently large $n$. Similarly, if $y\neq 0$ we have $\text{sgn}\,y_n=\text{sgn}\,y$ for large $n$.*